# Reverse chain rule vs Sum & Difference rules for integrating $\int(x - 1) dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, algebra-precalculus

I've been studying the basic rules of integration and learnt about the reverse chain rule quite recently. I was doing some practice exercises and there's this concept that I don't get. $\int (x - 1) dx$, using the sum and difference rule would give $\frac {x^2}{2} - x$ however applying the reverse chain to the same example gives $\frac{(x-1)^2}{2}$. Shouldn't the two expressions be equivalent? What am I missing?

Comment: In the first way gives $\frac{x^2}2-x+c_1$ for some value $c_1$, and in the second way gives $\frac{(x-1)^2}2+c_2 = \frac{x^2}2-x+\frac12+c_2$ for some value $c_2$. In **any** case, the value of the integral is $\frac{x^2}2-x+c$ for some $c$.

Comment: Oh I get it now.Thanks for the explanation!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are cases where different methods of integration seem to give different answers, but they all differ by a constant. For general antiderivatives, the value of the constant doesn't matter, but for particular antiderivatives, the value of the constant matters.

In your case, it seems as if you are finding the general antiderivative of $(x - 1)$. For this, the value of the constant of integration doesn't matter. One should not say that the first answer is the correct answer, or the second answer is the better answer. Both are valid.

Answer (score 0):

Since there is only a difference by the integral constant, those two are the same as the result of indefinite integration.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot that you get the integral constant.

$\frac{x^2}{2}-x+C=\frac{(x-1)^2}{2} +C$

Where C = -1